# get_dummies is not working in a. function - python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have this function where I am trying to execute a couple of commands. Everything is working except for the get_dummies function. I have an object column that I am trying to change to get_dummies.

```
def cleaning_data(data):
    data['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
    data.drop('Store_ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
    data.drop('Sale_ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
    pd.get_dummies(data, prefix=['State_holiday'])
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show a small subset of the data, so we can better understand the structure and contents ?